# Can we deep clone event object in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events

I want to copy the event object to another empty object. It is not cloning.

```
$scope.curretEvent = angular.copy(e);
```

where `e` is an event object

Comment: Yes we can. refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: It is not copying the event object(which is triggered by the click event)

Comment: What is exactly your problem. Where it goes wrong?

Comment: read the question care fully.. okay

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can deep clone it.

What happens when you do a `console.log(e)` in that function?
Does it output the result?

If so, check for typos ;)

I noticed that you wrote `$scope.curretEvent`(missing N), maybe you are using $scope.curre**n**tEvent in other places?

Comment: That is just variable name I have given.. we can given name but i am not getting the clone object of event